Proving inequality $y_0 \leq \dots \leq y_n \leq y_{n+1} \leq \sqrt{a} \leq \dots \leq x_{n+1} \leq x_n \leq \dots \leq x_n$
I want to calculate $\sqrt{a}, a \in \mathbb{R^+}$ with the following algorithm:
$y_n = \frac{a}{x_n}$,   $x_{n+1} = \frac{y_n+x_n}{2}, n=0,1,\dots,$,
with a start value $x_0 \geq \sqrt{a}$.
Now there is the inequality in my textbook which I do not understand.
$y_n \leq \dots \leq y_n \leq y_{n+1} \leq \dots \leq \sqrt{a} \leq \dots \leq x_{n+1} \leq x_n \leq \dots \leq x_0$.
For example I want to show that $y_0 \leq y_1$ but I get
$x_1 = \frac{y_0+x_0}{2}$.
But it's $y_0 \leq \sqrt{a}$ and $x_0 \geq \sqrt{a}$.
Any ideas what I am not seeing? Thanks for the help!

Look up Babylonian, Heron, Newton method to compute the root $\sqrt a$. Elementary proofs of convergence are standard exercises, you should find a lot of them online. For the last point it might be helpful to start with $x_1^2-x_0^2$, replace $x_1$ then $y_0$. This may fail, try again with $x_1^2-a$.

See this.

Thanks for the help! Now i showed that because of $\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n})>=\sqrt{a}$ is the same as $(\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}))^2>=0$, which always holds, it follows that $x_{n+1}<=x_n$ which is the same as showing that $x_{n} + \frac{a}{x_n}<=2x_n \implies \sqrt{a} <= x_n$, which I just proved. Would that work?
